# Violations of the proportional hazards assumption in Cox, how to use strata? R

Tags: r, survival, cox-model

I am doing a survival analysis in R for a university assignment. The data used is about crowdfounding and my goal is to know the time it takes for a campaign to be successful as well as the impact of different variables in this time.

I have performed the Kaplan-Meier analysis and then the Cox analysis, but when performing the tests, multiple variables violate the proportional hazards principle:

```
                             chisq df                    p
category               258.9569  8 < 0.0000000000000002
goal_cat                74.9250  1 < 0.0000000000000002
year_launch             62.3456  1   0.0000000000000029
quarter                  0.0772  1               0.7811
title_length_cat         9.2379  1               0.0024
description_length_cat   0.3063  1               0.5800
exclamation_mark         4.4367  1               0.0352
GLOBAL                 352.0203 14 < 0.0000000000000002
```

I have read that in this case, I can use the strata function. Still, I do not understand how to use it well and the results obtained as the output only show the variables that did not violate the proportional hazards principle.

```
complete_model <- coxph((survival_object) ~ category + goal_cat + year_launch + quarter + title_length_cat + description_length_cat + exclamation_mark,
                       data = data_sel)

testcox <- cox.zph(complete_model)
testcox

cox_strata <- coxph(survival_object ~ strata(category) + strata(goal_cat) + strata(year_launch) + quarter + strata(title_length_cat) + description_length_cat + strata(exclamation_mark),
                   data = data_sel) 


summary(cox_strata)
test_cox_strata <- cox.zph(cox_strata)
test_cox_strata
```

Am I using the strata function correctly? How should I interpret the output? Should I use another model, for example, a parametric model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you stratify by a categorical predictor in a Cox model, you allow for different baseline hazards for each level of the predictor. Without a common baseline hazard, you no longer have a way to evaluate hazard ratios among levels of that predictor. Although you don't show details of how your predictors are coded, you seem to be using strata properly. You will not, however, get hazard ratios for the stratified predictors. That might limit the usefulness of your model.

I like to evaluate the violations of proportional hazards (PH) by looking at the plots of scaled Schoenfeld residuals over time rather than just relying on the table of `cox.zph()`. See the [time-dependence vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/timedep.pdf). Your situation looks like it might be a large study where you have "statistically significant" violations of PH that might not be of much practical significance. That's a judgment call that requires looking at those plots. If the magnitudes of violations aren't large, your model might be good enough. Perhaps some simple handling of time-varying coefficients will improve the model adequately.

On the other hand, the apparent violations of PH might be due to mis-specification of the original survival model. Or perhaps the PH assumption isn't tenable at all and a parametric accelerated failure time model is required. Evaluate those possibilities.